# Go to page x button

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I always found it irritating that on the question site you cannot jump to pages in the middle of the site. As you see in the picture you can jump to page `2-5` and `4501`, but the questions in the middle are out of reach. You basically will never find out what questions are on page `2035`. You have to click your way through.

[image]

Of course one can say "why would you need that". If you have a question you can either ask for it or search for a keyword.

But I think it will be beneficial to have something like a `go to page X` button, so that one can occasionally scan through old questions to edit, comment or flag questions he would otherwise never have seen. This would imho help to keep the site clean. I know that there are all kinds of filters but sometimes I just like to read here a little to learn new things. But I will never see what (maybe useful) questions are on page `2035`.

Is there a way to jump to other pages? Is it possible to establish a `go to page X` button?

Comment: As a workaround, go to page 2 and then edit the url in your browser url field to jump to whatever page you want.

Comment: (if you just want to see some questions you would normally not see, try this site: https://www.isimonbrown.co.uk/dicestack/?site=tex&min_score=1&tagged=&answer_status=any)

Comment: [and btw, good look with your candidature!]

Comment: Main meta duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172246/adding-a-button-to-improve-navigation-through-the-questions

Comment: you can click the 5 button to get buttons for the later pages, but I just do as @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz suggests and put the page number in the url

Answer (score 2):

You can jump to a specific page eg this is page 7

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=newest&page=7

[image]

Once there, there are buttons for the next few pages eg 8 and 9 so you can click through to those.